# How to make a program end on a blank line in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i have an assignment where we had to create a program to calculate pay and have it loop, the prof wanted us to have it end if we input a blank line for either the pay or hours. So far this is what I have

```
answer = 'yes'

while answer == 'yes':

 hourly_pay = float(input('Enter hourly pay: '))

 if hourly_pay == 0:
    print ('Program Terminated')
    break

 hours = int(input('Enter hours worked: '))

 if hours == 0:
     print ('Program Terminated')
     break

 pay = hours * hourly_pay

 ot_pay = 1.5*hourly_pay

 if hours > 40:
     othours = hours - 40
     reghours = hours - othours
     pay = (ot_pay*othours)+(hourly_pay*reghours)

 print ('Pay = $',pay)

 answer = input ('repeat? (yes/no) ')

 while not (answer == 'yes' or answer == 'no'):
     answer = input('invalid response, answer (yes/no) ')
```

the program only terminates if the input is a zero but terminates with an error if only a blank line is input.

**EDIT**

Thanks to Ricky Kim, the program now works and terminates on both blank lines and zeros! 
This is the new code

```
answer = 'yes'

while answer == 'yes':

hourly_pay = input('Enter hourly pay: ')

if not hourly_pay:
    print('Program Terminated')
    break
else:
    hourly_pay = float(hourly_pay)

if hourly_pay == 0:
    print ('Program Terminated')
    break

hours = input('Enter hours worked: ')

if not hours:
    print('Program Terminated')
    break
else:
    hours=int(hours)

if hours == 0:
    print('Program Terminated')
    break

pay = hours * hourly_pay

ot_pay = 1.5*hourly_pay

if hours > 40:
    othours = hours - 40
    reghours = hours - othours
    pay = (ot_pay*othours)+(hourly_pay*reghours)

print ('Pay = $',pay)

answer = input ('repeat? (yes/no) ')

while not (answer == 'yes' or answer == 'no'):
    answer = input('invalid response, answer (yes/no) ')
```

Comment: I don't want to give away the answer, but you might try not converting the input to a numerical value the moment you get it - that way you can try comparing it to an empty string, or check the length of the gotten string.

Comment: This might also help `if not '': print('None string')` Also input will always be string so you can check for valid string and then proceed with type conversions to float/ints whatever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if it's empty before you convert to float or int. For example:

```
answer = 'yes'
while answer == 'yes':
    hourly_pay = input('Enter hourly pay: ')

    if not hourly_pay:
        print('empty line so quit')
        break
    else:
        hourly_pay = float(hourly_pay)

    if hourly_pay == 0:
        print ('Program Terminated')
        break
    #rest of your code here
```

Do same thing for hours.

Comment: @mad_ it terminates if you enter zero if you put the rest of code below. Do you need me to write the whole code?

Comment: @mad_ I added OP's code which checks for zero. Did not think I needed to include that as OP already has